# C# Make a money system with stages

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, currency

I'm asking myself, "what is the best way to create a money system in Unity with C# and money stages just like [this game](https://cash-inc.fandom.com/wiki/Currency) does?".

I already have some code (that doesn't work the way I want) that kinda does this, but it doesn't feel right to do it this way... There is always a small thought, that this won't work, because the max int number is `2.147.483.647` ant I definetly want to go higher than that.

```cs
    public string moneyFormatter (int num)
    {
        if (num >= 1000000000)
            return (num / 1000000).ToString("#,0B");

        if (num >= 100000000)
            return (num / 1000000000).ToString("0.#") + "B";

        if (num >= 10000000)
            return (num / 1000000).ToString("#,0M");

        if (num >= 1000000)
            return (num / 1000000).ToString("0.#") + "M";

        if (num >= 100000)
            return (num / 1000).ToString("#,0K");

        if (num >= 10000)
            return (num / 1000).ToString("#,0K");

        return num.ToString("#,0");
    }
```

Am I already doing it completely wrong?

Comment: If you want to go higher than Maxint, you have to use either long or decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these games use [Floating-point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) like `double` which can give you up to more than 10^308 at the cost of precision.

If you want precision but with the cost of speed and memory usage, check out [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0).

Comment: That has already helped me a lot, thank you very much. But I have one last question. How do I set the money names like "Septillion, Oktillion, Nonillion, Decillion, ... "? because checking `if(num >= 10000000000000000000000000000000)` doesn't feel and look right, and also comes with another problem. At some point, it says: "Integral constant is too large".

Comment: I assume you are using `double` if you could write like that? When you write 100, it's `100 in int32` (or int64 if you exceed int32 limit). After that C# can't support anymore. Try using `1E32` for example, it would be considered `double`, or `10000000000000000000000000000000000000D` to force it to be double.

Comment: If you use `BigInteger`, use [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.compareto?view=net-6.0) method, or just get the string length and see how many digits there are